# Error: ELF error: ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections

Tags: solana-program, rust

I've been struggling with this for hours now. I really don't know whats left to do.

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.8.0"

after I run solana program deploy  i get this error. Error: ELF error: ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections.

Ive updated my rust, my solana packages... I really don't know whats left to try. I've even attempted to use older versions to build the binary such as cargo-build-bpf. Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo, entrypoint::ProgramResult, pubkey::Pubkey, msg,
};

pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Your program logic goes here
    msg!("Hello, World!");


    Ok(())
}
```

```
// src/lib.rs

mod processor;

use processor::process_instruction;

solana_program::entrypoint!(process_instruction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `#![cfg(not(feature = "no-entrypoint"))]` at the beginning of `lib.rs`.